# Working xml data - Extract part of string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I am working on the text data in a string format. I'd like to know how to extract part of the string as below:

```
data = '<?xml version_history="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://dummydomain.facebook.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><id>aad232-c2cc-42ca-ac1e-e1d1b4dd55de</id><title<d:VersionType>3.0</d:VersionLabel><d:Name>XYZ Company</d:Title><d:New_x005f_h84_x005f_dsad_x005f_x003f_x005f_ m:null="true" /><d:Action_x005f_x0020_x005f_Status>Active<d:Stage>3. Contract Signed<d:ComplianceAssetId m:null="true" /><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">408</d:ID><d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-07-30T12:15:04Z</d:Modified><d:Author m:type="SP.FieldUserValue"><d:LookupId m:type="Edm.Int32">13</d:LookupId><d:LookupValue> Amy, Jackson</d:LookupValue><d:Email>Amy.Jackson@doe.com</d:Email><id>af62fe09-fds2-42ca-a12c1e-e1d1b4dd55de</id><title<d:VersionType>2.0</d:VersionLabel><d:Name>XYZ Company</d:Title><d:New_x005f_x0342fs_x005f_dsad_x005f_x003f_x005f_ m:null="true" /><d:Action_x005f_x0020_x005f_Status>Active<d:Stage>2. Active Discussion<d:ComplianceAssetId m:null="true" /><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">408</d:ID><d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-02-15T18:15:60Z</d:Modified><d:Author m:type="SP.FieldUserValue"><d:LookupId m:type="Edm.Int32">13</d:LookupId><d:LookupValue> Sam, Joseph</d:LookupValue><d:Email>Sam. Joseph @doe.com</d:Email></d:LookupValue><d:Email>Amy.Jackson@doe.com</d:Email><id>af62fe09-fds2-42ca-a12c1e-e1d1b4dd55de</id><title<d:VersionType>1.0</d:VersionLabel><d:Name>XYZ Company</d:Title><d:New_x005f_x0342fs_x005f_dsad_x005f_x003f_x005f_ m:null="true" /><d:Action_x005f_x0020_x005f_Status>Active<d:Stage>1. Exploratory<d:ComplianceAssetId m:null="true" /><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">408</d:ID><d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-07-15T10:20:04Z</d:Modified><d:Author m:type="SP.FieldUserValue"><d:LookupId m:type="Edm.Int32">13</d:LookupId><d:LookupValue> Sam, Joseph</d:LookupValue><d:Email>Sam. Joseph @doe.com</d:Email>'
```

[image]

I want to extract all <d:VersionType>,<d:Name>,<d:Stage>,and <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">

Expected outputs:

```
d:VersionType    d:Name        d:Stage         d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime"
3.0              XYZ Company   3. Contract     2020-07-30T12:15:04Z
2.0              XYZ Company   2. Contract     2020-02-15T18:15:60Z
1.0              XYZ Company   1. Exploratory  2019-07-15T10:20:04Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using beautiful soup as it lets you parse xml, html and other documents. Such files are already in a specific structure, and you don't have to build a regex expression from scratch, making your job a lot easier.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

version_type = [item.text for item in soup.findAll('d:VersionType')] # gives ['3.0', '2.0', '1.0']
```

Replace `d:VersionType` with other elements you want `(d:Name, d:Stage, ..)` to extract their contents as well.

Comment: Thank you, Suraj! Glad to learn bs4 can also do the work, and it's easy to implement.

Comment: Yes, it helps you make use of the structure in `xml, html` documents. Glad it was of help to you :)